# ngInclude using AngularJS and JavaFX

Tags: angularjs, javafx-2, javafx, angularjs-ng-include

The problem I want to solve is how to inject a separate html file into the main one in JavaFX Webview + AngularJS. I tried to use AngularJS [ngInclude](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude), but maybe there is a better way to achieve it? Ater debugging AngularJS ng-include I failed due to unsupported jar:// protocolol. Is there any way to load html files using AngularJS framework and JavaFX? HTML files are inside the jar file and AngularJS is the framework. Should I turn away from one of them or there is some solution?

Details:

I load from index.html subpage1.html using nginclude dircetive. It works outside JavaFx but fails when I use Webview inside JavaFX.

Comment: I'm guessing a but...  I was under the impression that ngInclude accesses files that are "web accessible" over HTTP. It sounds like your JavaFX Webview is not using the HTTP Protocol; which may be confusing Angular.

Comment: In fact, using the file:// protocol outside the WebView, ngInclude works fine. The problem I want to solve is how to inject a separate  html file into the main one in JavaFX WebView. Maybe there is better way than ngInclude?